# How to save file with pickles and usual characters?

Tags: python, database, pickle

I needed to save a list that contained strings and integers and that was easy to access the elements in another notebook (like for example through data[i]).

I saved the list

`data = ["eos", 5, 10, 20]`

with pickles:

```
with open(path + '/data.txt', 'wb') as f: 
   pickle.dump(data, f)
```

However, it is important that I can read the saved file. When I opened it, it was saved with special characters, like this one in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzWzi.png)

Other than that, in python, I be able to call the elements. I used

```
f= pickle.load(open(path + str("\\") + str("data.txt"), 'rb'))
```

and `data[0]` returned 'eos' correctly.

How can I save the file in a way that I can read it (that doesn't have those strange characters in the photo)?

Comment: pickle uses a binary format. Thus, when you open it in a text editor, some of the bytes are interpreted as weird characters.
If possible, you could try to use `json` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead of pickle. JSON is a text format that is human readable.

Comment: I think that pickling might not be the right choice for you. Is there a reason you chose pickle?

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is Python-specific, and it also changes over time as improvements are made. If you want to be able to read the file with other programs, you should choose another format.

If your data is a table, which is what your example loosely implies, I would suggest CSV (comma-separated values) because it can be opened in any spreadsheet program, including Google Sheets and LibreOffice. There is a `csv` module in Python that you can use for that purpose. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.

As another user pointed out, JSON (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is another option that's commonly used today, especially when the data you need to store is non-homogeneous. It's has more overhead than CSV and it slightly more tedious and error-prone to edit by hand, if that's something that you expect to do.

If you really, really want to use the Pickle format, you can pass `protocol=0` as a parameter to `dump()`, which will cause the file to be written in a less efficient text-based format instead of binary, although if your data includes any non-printable characters, the `.pkl` file will inherently become binary.